# Why $\hat{f}$ and $\epsilon$ are independent, in bias-variance tradeoff proof?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

### Backgrounds

I'm following [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Bias%E2%80%93variance_decomposition_of_squared_error)'s proof of the **bias-variance tradeoff**.

The page gives the following proof.

---

### Proof([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Bias%E2%80%93variance_decomposition_of_squared_error))

Denote $\hat{f}$ : an estimate of a deterministic function $f$, where the observations $y$ has the model

$$
y = f + \epsilon
$$

where $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon) = 0$ and $\mathrm{Var}(\epsilon) = \sigma^2$. Since $\mathrm{Var}(y) = \mathrm{Var}(\epsilon) = \sigma^2$, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} \left[ (y - \hat{f})^2 \right] &=  \mathbb{E} \left[ (f + \epsilon - \hat{f} + \mathbb{E}(\hat{f}) - \mathbb{E}(\hat{f}))^2 \right] \\[8pt]
&= \mathbb{E} \left[ (f - \mathbb{E}(\hat{f}))^2 + (\hat{f} - \mathbb{E}(\hat{f}))^2 + \epsilon^2 \right] \\[8pt]
&= [\mathrm{Bias} (\hat{f})]^2 + \mathrm{Var}(\hat{f}) + \sigma^2
\end{aligned}
$$

where the second equality is guaranteed from eliminating all the cross-product terms based on the **fact that** **$\hat{f}$ and $\epsilon$ are independent.** (According to Wiki page)

---

### Question

Why **$\hat{f}$ and $\epsilon$ are independent**? Here is a **possible counterexample**. Say $\hat{f}$ is a linear regression estimate of $f$, i.e.

$$
\hat{f}(x_{n1}, \cdots, x_{np}) := \hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} x_{n1} + \cdots + \hat{\beta_p} x_{np}, \forall n
$$

where $x_{ij}$ denotes the $j$th dimensional information of $i$th observation, and $\hat{\beta}_i$ (i=0, \cdots, p) are the estimated parameters. It is well-known that

$$
\hat{f} = \hat{\mathbf{y}} = X (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \mathbf{y}
$$

where $X$ is just the data matrix and $\hat{\beta} := (\hat{\beta_0}, \cdots, \hat{\beta_p})$.

We know that $\hat{f} = \hat{\mathbf{y}}$ is **never independent** with $\mathbf{y}$ (which is a **function** of $\epsilon$),  because it **contains** $\mathbf{y}$!

---

How should I understand the Wiki page's proof?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not independent of training data. In the derivation they are aiming at test error. Basically new x and $\hat{f}(x)$ values. They are independent of $\epsilon$

Comment: Keep in mind that the derivation above assumes that the true model is known. Actually the independence argument sound strange to me too; $Bias(f)$ and $\epsilon$ is related. However the above decomposition is permitted.

Comment: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~smyth/courses/cs274/readings/xing_singh_CMU_bias_variance.pdf This has less sloppy treatment of the derivation, clearly separating the expectation calculations for training and test.

Comment: @CowboyTrader Thank you for the elegant material, although $\mathbb{E}_{D_n}$ is kind of unfamiliar notation. I will be very grateful if you could clarify the point.

Comment: $E_{D_n}$ means take average with respect to training data, and $E_{X,Y}$ is to average over test data (we are trying to know how good model is over new data points not over training which is always optimistic). As I said before $\hat{f}$ depends on training data but clearly cannot depend on something it hasn't seen before, the test data.

Comment: @CowboyTrader Thank you for the beautiful explanation